# Are questions regarding TENS units (like this specific one) on or off topic?

Tags: discussion

I just posted this question regarding TENS units for pain caused by physical fitness activity on the Health SE: [Are “Class 2” prescription TENS units any better than OTC TENS units?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/4326/are-class-2-prescription-tens-units-any-better-than-otc-tens-units)

I wanted to post it on this SE because I think it would get a much better response.  But it looks like it may be off-topic on this SE.

Did I do the right thing by posting it on the Health SE instead of this SE?

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that would be off topic here, since it's not ***directly*** related to physical fitness. Nearly everything is related to fitness, but it's about how direct the connection is.

Not only is the question not directly related to fitness, but it takes it further and goes into the product choice and product features.

You'll get some answers over on Health I'd imagine.

Comment: Thanks Eric!  I appreciate your feedback.